# Telerik RadDatePicker error related to DbSelectedDate

Tags: telerik, raddatepicker

I'm using Telerik in one project and I have some troubles with it.
Specifically, I want to use a RadDatePicker, and I defined it as below:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
<telerik:RadDatePicker ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" Width="140px" Skin="Windows7"
        DateInput-EmptyMessage="End Date" MinDate="01/01/2000" MaxDate="01/01/2050">
    <Calendar>
        <SpecialDays>
            <telerik:RadCalendarDay Repeatable="Today" ItemStyle-CssClass="rcToday">
            </telerik:RadCalendarDay>
        </SpecialDays>
     </Calendar>
 </telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

And in code behind I use:

```
txtStartDate.DbSelectedDate = Date.Today.AddDays(-7).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

But when I build I get the following error

Error   62  ...: error BC30456: 'DbSelectedDate' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'.

Any idea what can be?
In another page I have the RadDatePicker defined the same way and it works there

Thanks

Comment: The definition of the Control in the design.cs file is incorrect. Verify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this error seems to be a side effect.

It occured in one application which was converted from Website-type project to webapp type project. After initial importing files, there were about 2000 errors (most caused by missing / wrong references or namespaces).

I ignored that error and fixed other, and the suddenly the error dissapeared.